# Android application to download all videos from a YouTube playlist

Tags: android, youtube

I am looking for an Android application that can download all videos from a YouTube playlist. If possible, it should be free and allow to choose

- the download location
- the video quality
- which video to download

Comment: Ensuing meta discussion: [Shall this site support questions on youtube downloaders?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/805/shall-this-site-support-questions-on-youtube-downloaders)

Comment: Pip and YouTube-DL not good enough?

Answer (score 1):

I believe TubeMate (free) can do that. It's not on the Play Store so you will have to download the .APK file and "sideload" it

[TubeMate](http://tubemate.net/)